# Cron Expression to be executed every n weeks

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I am trying to write a Cron expression that triggers every n weeks.

I have thought about something like:

```
0   0  */21 *   *

2013-09-01 00:00:00
2013-09-22 00:00:00
2013-10-01 00:00:00
2013-10-22 00:00:00
```

Per [this](http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php?cron=0%20%20%200%20%20%2a/21%20%2a%20%20%20%2a&iterations=10&test=Test) Cron tester

But it triggers every 1st in addition to the 21st.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), then you may be able to accomplish that schedule with a [SimpleTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html) instead:

```
     Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
         .withIdentity(triggerKey("myTrigger", "myGroup"))
         .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
             .repeatHourlyForever(n * 7 * 24))
         .startAt(...)
         .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

The '/' syntax specifies the increment during the period and not a repeat interval. Admittedly a subtle and confusing difference.

In this case there is only one available increment (21 days) during the 1 month period. The first number specifies the value to start with, in this case 0. Specifying '*' before the '/' is equivalent to specifying 0. So the job will only fire on the first day and at 21 days.

If you only want to fire the job once a month and not repeatedly then you could use the expression `0 0 21 * *`.

If you want a job to trigger at a regular interval then you can use a Quartz `SimpleTrigger` with a `repeatInterval` specified.